# This is a Java program I tried. But I could not find where I did wrong with the code

Tags: java

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package exams;

public class ExamDetails {

    public static void main (String[] args){

        StudentResults aStudent = new StudentResults();


        String sName = aStudent.fullName("Bill Gates");
        System.out.println(sName);

    }

    class StudentResults{

    private String Full_Name;
    private String Exam_Name;
    private String Exam_Score;
    private String Exam_Grade;

    StudentResults(){
        Full_Name = "No Name Given";
        Exam_Name = "Unknown";
        Exam_Score = "No Score";
        Exam_Grade = "Unknown";
    }

    String fullName(String aName){

        Full_Name = aName;
        return Full_Name;

    }

}

}
```

Comment: So whats the problem?

Comment: Try adding static keyword to your StudentResults class. Something like this: static class StudentResults { ... }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make following changes :

```
public class ExamDetails {

    static  StudentResults aStudent = new StudentResults();
    public static void main (String[] args){




        String sName = aStudent.fullName("Bill Gates");
        System.out.println(sName);

    }

    static class StudentResults{

    private String Full_Name;
    private String Exam_Name;
    private String Exam_Score;
    private String Exam_Grade;

    StudentResults(){
        Full_Name = "No Name Given";
        Exam_Name = "Unknown";
        Exam_Score = "No Score";
        Exam_Grade = "Unknown";
    }

    String fullName(String aName){

        Full_Name = aName;
        return Full_Name;

    }

}

}
```

Or second option is to declare `StudentResults` in seperate file

Answer (score 0):

```
StudentResults aStudent = new ExamDetails().new StudentResults();
```

Do this in main function.

`StudentResult` is an inner class to the `ExamDetails` class and it is not `static`.

So to use non static member in static main function, you need reference of class containing that member.

Answer (score 0):

Another options :

```
package various;

public class  StudentResults{

    public static void main (String[] args){

        StudentResults aStudent = new StudentResults();

        String sName = aStudent.fullName("Bill Gates");
        System.out.println(sName);

    }

    private String Full_Name;
    private String Exam_Name;
    private String Exam_Score;
    private String Exam_Grade;

    StudentResults(){
        Full_Name = "No Name Given";
        Exam_Name = "Unknown";
        Exam_Score = "No Score";
        Exam_Grade = "Unknown";
    }

    String fullName(String aName){

        Full_Name = aName;
        return Full_Name;

    }
}
```